# docker fails to start

Tags: docker, centos7, systemd

I am running docker on CentOS 7. (docker from centos repo. not that of docker-engine). docker was running perfectly but for some reasons i tried to reinstall it. Unfortunately docker.service refused to start and shows me the next couple of errors:

```
Jan 24 15:19:28 fms-provisioner-4.novalocal systemd[1]: Job docker.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.

Jan 24 15:21:30 fms-provisioner-4.novalocal systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Docker Application Container Engine.

-- Subject: Unit docker.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel 
-- Unit docker.service has failed.
-- The result is dependency.

Jan 24 15:21:30 fms-provisioner-4.novalocal systemd[1]: Job docker.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.

Jan 24 15:28:49 fms_k8s_minion2 systemd[1]: [/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service:17] Unknown lvalue '--add-runtime docker-runc' in section 'Service' 

Jan 24 15:43:09 fms_k8s_minion2 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Docker Application Container Engine.
-- Subject: Unit docker.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel 
-- Unit docker.service has failed.
-- The result is dependency.
```

Please may someone tell me what's going on ?

Comment: Which Docker version have you installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your answers but i forgot to mention that i am using flannel with docker. it such case, flannel was down do docker won't to start.
that's mainly what was causing my issue.
sorry for disturbing.

Answer (score 1):

Try to restart docker daemon and service by using 

`sudo systemctl daemon-reload`

and 

`sudo systemctl restart docker`

if this do not help than Remove docker and try 
`curl -sSL http://get.docker.com | sh 
   sudo systemctl restart docker`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your Docker build is configured to use `runc:

```
 [/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service:17] Unknown lvalue '--add-runtime docker-runc' in section 'Service'
```

You could install `runc`, but that probably won't fix the issue:

```
sudo yum install runc
```

runC is lightweight, portable implementation of the the Open Container Format (OCF), you can find more about it in [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en/red-hat-enterprise-linux-atomic-host/7/paged/managing-containers/chapter-5-finding-and-running-containers-without-docker).

Anyway the `--add-runtime` flag was added in [Docker 1.12](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/22845), unless there's at least `docker-engine` 1.12.0 in your repository remove the flag in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` and reload the service:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart docker
```